# What type of information structure does “dann aber” signal in this sentence?

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context, conjunction

> Das gelingt ihm auch anfangs; dann aber wird er in einen regelrechten Kampf verwickelt.

I cannot decide whether *aber* denotes a turn of event development or a direct contrast between the situations of the initial stage of the affair and the ensuing development.

By *turn of event development* I mean the speaker uses *aber* to denote the development of the affair as time goes by, with the temporal correlation between the two clauses standing in the foreground of the speaker’s perception.

By *direct contrast* I mean the speaker perceives the different situations of the initial stage (anfangs) and the later one (dann) as side-by-side objects, with the temporal interrelation between the two stages being backgrounded away from the foreground.

In addition, I’d like to ask whether *aber* is used as a conjunction or an adverb or a modal particle in this sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the meaning of the sentence, I am leaning towards your *turn of event* description although I find it hard to see a difference between the two. There is certainly a direct-contrast type of element in the entire thing but I feel the main importance is on the sequential aspect where the later situation is substantially different from before because of how time passed. In any case, you should view *dann aber* as belonging together. This is supported by different variants of moving the two into other parts of the sentence:

> […] er wird dann aber in einen regelrechten Kampf verwickelt.
>
> […] in einen regelrechten Kampf wird er dann aber verwickelt.
>
> <strike>[…] er wird aber in einen regelrechten Kampf dann verwickelt.</strike>

It feels best to keep the two together.

*Aber* cannot be a conjunction here, because it is not in zeroth position — the entire first position is filled by *dann aber* which is also not a conjunction as a whole because it is immediately followed by the finite verb.

The entire *dann aber* is used adverbially. And to the best of my knowledge I would say that both its fragments are adverbs, too. We can construct the sentence with both halfs of *dann aber* (but one requires reordering):

> […] dann wird er in einen regelrechten Kampf verwickelt.
>
> […] er wird aber in einen regelrechten Kampf verwickelt.

And it is also possible to pull *dann* and *aber* apart:

> […] dann wird er aber in einen regelrechten Kampf verwickelt.

My feeling tells me that this last version focusses on the *aber* more, and may come closer to what you called *direct contrast*.

Having *aber* in first position would usually turn it into a conjunction, by the way:

> […] aber *er wird* (dann) in einen regelrechten Kampf verwickelt.

(Note how *er* now occupies the free first position since *aber* has zeroth.)